# Filtering array inside a for loop throws warning VueJS

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure if this is an issue or I'm doing something wrong. Using VueJS, I have a filtering function inside a v-for and works fine, but it throws a warning in the console, [this](https://codepen.io/mmansilla/pen/KyWZKM) is a minimal example of the problem.

As you can see, I need to filter relational data from a different array hence the function getClan(), which returns the an array, so I need to use the data from the first element. So far so good, but when the v-for loop ends I got this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: this.clans.filter(...)[0] is undefined"
```

The message is displayed on Chrome and Firefox console, for some reason is not displayed on codepen's local console, I'm guessing this is isolated from warnings somehow.

The warning occurs only at the end of the for loop and when trying with a larger set of the data same happens.

Thinking about using computed properties but you can't pass arguments on those.

Comment: For future reference, please make questions self-contained rather than depending on external services like codepen or jsfiddle (SO's snippet tool does everything they do, and it ensures questions don't become unusable due to link rot)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I guess was being lazy about it, but you're right, the code isn't long and would improve question readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when your array filter doesn't match anything: you try to access the first index of the returned value, which doesn't exist.

You'll need to check to see whether there are results instead:

```
getClan(x) {
    var clan = this.clans.filter(clan=>clan.id==x)
    if (clan.length > 0) {
      return clan[0].name
    } else {
      return "Peasant"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one was pretty obvious. Just had to do a little change, since filter returns an array even when it has one item just changed the condition to clan.length>0 and works!.

Comment: @deadPoet ooh, good catch; I removed the erroneous part of the answer, thanks!

Comment: no problem, I'm thinking the problem is the filter call inside v-for directive, when it reaches the last element somehow getClan(x) still gets a null parameter and thats the reason for the warning, so this should fix the problem, Thanks again.